# Compare raw strings of different types and store them properly

Tags: rust, vulkan

I am currently learning Rust with Vulkan (via the `ash` bindings).
This is the basic code of my problem:

```rust
const REQUESTED_LAYERS: &'static [&'static str] = &["VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"];

let available_layers: HashSet<[i8, _]> = entry
        .enumerate_instance_layer_properties()?
        .iter()
        .map(|l| l.layer_name)
        .collect();

let mut enabled_layers: Vec<*const c_char> = vec![];
```

Now my goal is to filter the `REQUIRED_LAYERS` depending on the `available_layers`. I think it's best explained with some pseudo code:

```rust
for required_layer in REQUIRED_LAYERS {
    if available_layers.contains(required_layer) {
        enabled_layers.push(required_layer);
    }
}
```

It is pretty straight forward, but the problem are the types. My `REQUIRED_LAYERS` slice is of type `&[&str]`, `available_layers` is a `HashSet<[i8, _]>` and `enabled_layers` **must** be a `Vec<*const c_char>`. (But the types in the containers are all strings, just represented differently).

Now my question is effectively how to convert all types inside of the containers so that the logic of the pseudo code would work.

I already tried creating new vectors of type `Vec<CString>` and then *again* new vectors of type `Vec<CStr>` but I still didn't get everything to work. This also ended in a bunch of chaos with so many vectors that I don't think are required.

This is what I got working:

```rust
let requested_layers: Vec<CString> = REQUESTED_LAYERS
        .iter()
        .map(|s| CString::new(*s).unwrap())
        .collect();

let available_layers: HashSet<CString> = entry
        .enumerate_instance_layer_properties()?
        .iter()
        .map(|l| unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(l.layer_name.as_ptr()).to_owned() })
        .collect();

let mut enabled_layers: Vec<CString> = vec![];

for requested_layer in requested_layers {
    if available_layers.contains(&requested_layer) {
        println!("Added layer! {:?}", &requested_layer);
        enabled_layers.push(requested_layer);
    } else {
        println!("Layer not available! {:?}", &requested_layer);
    }
}

let enabled_layers_raw: Vec<*const c_char> = enabled_layers.iter().map(|l| l.as_ptr()).collect();
```

But I would love to know if you can achieve this more elegantly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry to bring you the bad news, but you *can't* convert `&str` to `*const c_char` because the latter needs to be null-termianted, and the former isn't. Your approach with `Vec<CString>` and `Vec<CStr>` pointing to the C strings sounds exactly right; you should show it, and we might be able to help you make it more elegant. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69438074/1600898) for a related example.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for your comment! I tried again and actually got it working pretty quickly. But I would love to see if there is a more elegant way :)